# How to do conditional promise chaining

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, promise, angular-promise

I'm learning promises/typescript/angular and I want to chain promises conditionally.

This is the actual state of my method:

```
private executePromiseModificationEvenement<T>(edition: Models.CalendrierParametresModelEdition, modeCreation: boolean, deferred: ng.IDeferred<T>) {
    var promise: ng.IPromise<Object>;

    //Step1
    if (modeCreation) {
        promise = this.$calendrier.Actions.enregistrerEvenementOutlook(edition);
    } else {
        promise = this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenementOutlook(edition);
    }

    if (this.$scope.outlook) {
        promise.then((x) => {
            if (x != '') edition.idOutlook = x.toString();;
            return deferred.resolve();
        }, (x) => {
            return deferred.reject();
        });
    } else {
        //Step2
        promise.then((x) => {
            if (x != '') edition.idOutlook = x.toString();
            return this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenement(edition);
        }, (x) => {
            //Ajout MessageBox message error
            return this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenement(edition);
        })
        //Step3
        .then((x) => {
            if (edition.opportunite != null) this.$rootScope.$broadcast("pushEchangeOpportunite", { idOpportunite: parseInt(edition.opportunite), action: 2, IdContact: edition.id, Libelle: edition.title, StartDate: moment(edition.start).toDate() });
            return deferred.resolve();
        }, (x) => {
            return deferred.reject();
        });
    }
}
```

I'm familiar of async/await of C#, neither of which gives a problem with conditional chaining, but I'm having trouble achieving the same with promises.

Is it to correct to put a **.then** not just after the creation of the promise but after an **if** ?

Is it possible that the **.then** may never be called because the promise is already finished?

Comment: Maybe this would be better suited for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Script47 not quite. The OP wants help adding additional functionality to their code. That would be Off-Topic at Code Review.

Comment: @Zak the OP doesn't actually appear to have asked a question or stated that he has any problem except for what's in the title, which sounds just like a Code Review request.

Comment: @Pak the step you're missing is to actually `return` the final value from any `.then` chain [ i.e. `return promise.then(...) `]   Without that the entire function will return with an already resolved `undefined` value immediately.

Comment: @Alnitak Ah, my bad. It was the last sentence that threw me. Upon re-reading, you appear to be correct.

Comment: Its not a good question on any site, neither here or CR. Being off-topic here doesn't make it on-topic there.

Comment: Please edit your text to include a very specific question.  Right now you have a broad title and a bunch of code and no clear question posed.  The lack of a clear question is why you're getting downvotes.  A good question will include a description of what specific problem you're trying to solve, what you're current code does when you execute it and exactly which part of your code you want help with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to chain promises together in any order or use ifs, loops, whatever.

If you call `.then` on a resolved promise then it will execute instantly, so that's fine too.
The only way the then will not be called is if the promise chain is never resolved or is rejected.

A normal way of chaining might be to return the next object from within the function.  This tends to be neater than calling `deferred.resolve()`.

E.g.

```
var promise = this.$calendrier.Actions.enregistrerEvenementOutlook(edition);
promise = promise.then(function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
})
promise = promise.then(function (x) {
    return 2 * x;
})
```

or

```
var promise =
    this.$calendrier.Actions.enregistrerEvenementOutlook(edition)
    .then(function (x) {
        return 2 * x;
    })
    .then(function (x) {
        return 2 * x;
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

`executePromiseModificationEvenement()` doesn't need a Deferred. There's absolutely no value in passing one in. Instead, you should be looking to return the promise returned by a promise chain formed within the function. The caller function(s) will need only a minor change.

Straightforwardly, your function can be rewritten with a series of (conditional) `promise = promise.then(...)` statements with a final `return promise`. Some of the code repetition can also be addressed.

```
private executePromiseModificationEvenement<T>(edition: Models.CalendrierParametresModelEdition, modeCreation: boolean<T>) {
    var promise: ng.IPromise<Object>;
    promise = modeCreation ?
        this.$calendrier.Actions.enregistrerEvenementOutlook(edition) :
        this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenementOutlook(edition);

    promise = promise.then((x) => {
        if (x != '') {
            edition.idOutlook = x.toString();
        }
    });

    if (!this.$scope.outlook) {
        promise = promise.then(() => {
            return this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenement(edition);
        }, () => {
            return this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenement(edition);
        })
        .then((x) => {
            if (edition.opportunite != null) {
                this.$rootScope.$broadcast("pushEchangeOpportunite", {
                    idOpportunite: parseInt(edition.opportunite), 
                    action: 2, 
                    IdContact: edition.id, 
                    Libelle: edition.title, 
                    StartDate: moment(edition.start).toDate() 
                }); 
            }
        });
    }
    return promise;
}
```

However, that may not be the best solution.

It *may* be more appropriate to perform the `if(this.$scope.outlook)` test at the point where `this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenement()...` is called, during chain settlement rather than during the chain building phase. The result will not necessarily be the same because `this.$scope.outlook` will have had an opportunity to change state.

Personally, I would guess that performing the test later *is* more appropriate (or inconsequential). If so, the promise chain can be built unconditionally and all the tests performed internally, which if nothing else, is much tidier.

```
private executePromiseModificationEvenement<T>(edition: Models.CalendrierParametresModelEdition, modeCreation: boolean<T>) {
    return (modeCreation ? 
        this.$calendrier.Actions.enregistrerEvenementOutlook(edition) :
        this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenementOutlook(edition))
    .then((x) => {
        if (x != '') {
            edition.idOutlook = x.toString();
        }
    })
    .catch((x) => { return x; }) // this mid-chain-error-recovery line is rather odd but consistent with the original code. It may be better placed one step earlier.
    .then(() => {
        if (!this.$scope.outlook) {
            return this.$calendrier.Actions.modifierEvenement(edition)
            .then(() => {
                if (edition.opportunite != null) {
                    this.$rootScope.$broadcast("pushEchangeOpportunite", {
                        'idOpportunite': parseInt(edition.opportunite),
                        'action': 2,
                        'IdContact': edition.id,
                        'Libelle': edition.title,
                        'StartDate': moment(edition.start).toDate()
                    }); 
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```